# A Grails application demoing the Stack Exchange API

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

I created this mostly for fun, with a little bit of learning thrown in. It's a
super-simple implementation of a client for the Stack Exchange API written in [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29).
It served as a quick means of exploring and learning about the API, and I hope others
might use it to do the same.

#### License

Seeing as I've never released anything with a license before, I pick... the [Apache licence](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

#### Download

Source download is available on GitHub at http://github.com/kellyrob99/stackoverflow-api-grails. The implementation is described on my blog in *[A Grails App Demoing the Stack Exchange API](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2010/06/02/a-grails-app-demoing-the-stackexchange-api/)*.

#### Platform

This should run on all platforms and has been tested in [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat).

### Contact

Kelly Robinson. Please leave a comment on the blog if you need to contact me.

### Code

This is a [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) and Grails (v1.3.1) applications written using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and its excellent Grails integration.
Code is available on GitHub, http://github.com/kellyrob99/stackoverflow-api-grails. Feel free to fork it and do with it what you will. Cheers.